# Clique Percolation Method calculation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

According to Clique Percolation Method as shown in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_percolation_method)

I could not understand why the result of Graph1 is Graph2 if we assign k to be=2,
According to the definition of CPM, then the cluster resulting from cliques must be 4 cliques not only 2, because also :{2,4,12} and {8,9,13} is also maximal clique of size k=3 and sharing the big cluster into 2 nodes  so here 2> k-1 and as I understand the resulting cluster should be created for it ?
anyway the question why there are only 2 clusters ? not 4 clusters as I expect by the definition above or in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_percolation_method)..

[image]

[image]

Comment: see also: 12 is sharing between two maximal cliques : {2,4,12} and {11,12,13}, the same also with : 13 which is also shared with {8,9,13} and {11,12,13} ? Am I wrong ?

Comment: any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have a misunderstanding. Here is a list of misunderstandings:

1. K represents the number of nodes for the clique. For example, k=3 means a triangle, k=4 means a square with 2 diagonal edges also... etc, That's why assigning k as 2 doesn't mean anything. Although it is okay with the definition you can find n! (n factorial) cliques in a graph that has n nodes. So it doesn't show anything when you assign k to 2.
2. Actually it should be 3 clusters which are {5,6,7,10,8,9}, {12,11,13}, {1,3,5,4,2}. 5 is the overlapping node between 2 clusters so it should be in both clusters and there should be 2 seperate clusters in that region. If you assign k to 3 i think it will correct it in the way i said.
3. To say that two cliques are adjacent, they need to share k-1 nodes. Imagine 2 cliques which are {1,2,3} and {5,3,2}, since they share 2 and 3 they will adjacent clique and represent a cluster together (if there is no more adjacent clique). So the problem you have been suffering is not problem actually. There is no problem with 12 and 13 nodes. Since {2,4,12} and {11,12,13} share only one node they are not adjacent, that means these 2 cliques have no connection. It is same with  {8,9,13} and {11,12,13} subgraphs. They have only 1 common node, there is no connection between these subgraphs.

I hope these helped you. I think you need to read the text again, you can also read the original paper instead of wiki, that helps more.